# Why is value of let point not being reassigned

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have a variable called point which update to hold the lat and lng values of a location. However I the value of point does not update when I reassign inside the if function. Once inside the if function the value of point does get reassigned and prints the correct value but when it leaves the if function it goes back to being undefined.

```
generateWayPoint(address: string): string {
  let point;
  const point4 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.496144, -3.182328);

  const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      point = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                     results[0].geometry.location.lng());
      this.wayPoint = point;
      console.log('a point in the making', this.wayPoint);
      console.log('a wayPoint in the making', this.wayPoint);

    } else {
      console.log('Geocode was not successful for the followin reason:', status);

    }
  });


  console.log('a point how it should be:', point4);
  console.log('comparing a point', point);
  console.log('comparing a wayPoint', this.wayPoint);
  return point;
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with let.

The geocode function gets called async, so at the time it prints point the first time, it is really not assigned.